# convergences of improper irrational Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

> Finding Convergence or Divergence of $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}dx$$

What i Try:

I am trying to prove $(x^2+1)\leq \sqrt{x^6+1}$ for all $x\geq 0$

$(x^2+1)^2\leq (x^6+1)\Longrightarrow x^4+2x^2+1\leq x^6+1$

Getting $x^4+2x^2\leq x^6$ but which is false.

How do i finding that integral is converges. Help me Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(\forall x\ge 1)\;\; x^6+1>x^6$$

$$\implies \; (\forall x\ge 1)\;\; \sqrt{x^6+1}> \sqrt{x^6}$$

$$\implies \;\;(\forall x\ge 1)\;\; \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}<\frac{1}{x^3}$$

but $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^3} $ converges, thus, by comparison criterion, $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^6+1}}$ converges and finally

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^6+1}} \;\; is \;\; convergent$$

Comment: Thabks Haman. But How do i find in $x\in[0,1]$

Comment: @jacky $\int_0^\infty f$ and $\int_1^\i fty f$ have same nature. the bound $0$ is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks Hamam But still did not understand well.

Comment: @jacky Your integral is improper because of the infinite bound, not zero.